# Excel difference between dates not working

Tags: excel

I have the following data in columns:

```
            A            B
1       1/08/2021    29/11/2021
```

These values are the result of some searches from other columns with this formula:

```
=MINIFS('sheet2'!$G:$G,'sheet2'!$F:$F,$E1)
```

Both the source cells and the resulting cells are of type `date`

I then look to get the `DATEDIF` between these and I end up with `#NAME?`

```
=DATEDIF($A1,$B1,”M”) /* Corrected the above "W" to "M"... typo! */
```

[image]

I tried `DATEVALUE` on the search result cells like this:

```
=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE($A1),DATEVALUE($B1),”M”)
```

But I end up with `#VALUE?` so the resulting values from the searches are not seen as dates. What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "W" on `=DATEDIF($A1,$B1,”W”)` is not a valid unit, accordingly to Microsoft's documentation ([here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)).

The list of valid units is:

- "Y" : The number of complete years in the period.
- "M" : The number of complete months in the period.
- "D" : The number of days in the period.
- "MD": The difference between the days in start_date and
  end_date. The months and years of the dates are ignored. Not
  recommended, as there are known limitations with it.
- "YM" : The difference between the months in start_date and end_date. The days
  and years of the dates are ignored
- "YD" : The difference between the
  days of start_date and end_date. The years of the dates are ignored.

Comment: Sorry guys! I had a typo. "W" should have been "M"... still have the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

The `#NAME?` error is because you are using left and right quotation marks instead of straight quotation marks.  eg: `“W”` instead of "W".

If you correct that, you will see a `#NUM!` error because `W` is not a valid argument for the function.

See MS Help for the `DATEDIF` function for more information as well as a warning about the `MD` unit.